# Unresolved External Symbol? error lnk2019

Tags: external, symbols

I was wondering if anyone knew what this error meant.

Thanks

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall LinkedList,class std::allocator > >::LocItem *>::decreasekey(class PriorityList,class std::allocator > >::LocItem * const &)" (?decreasekey@?$LinkedList@HPAVLocItem@?$PriorityList@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@@@QAEXABQAVLocItem@?$PriorityList@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall PriorityList,class std::allocator > >::decreasekey(class PriorityList,class std::allocator > >::Locator)" (?decreasekey@?$PriorityList@HV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAEXVLocator@1@@Z)

Comment: Could you give us some more information? Sample code?

Answer (score 2):

It simply means there is a symbol that was not defined. Check your spelling and make sure it exists and is defined in your code.

[MSDN Help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there was anything more specific you could get from it...

Comment: Looks like LinkedList's decreasekey method?